# Simplify a complicated count SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is a way to simplify the following SQL statement. This is my table.

```
| SID | name | l1 | l2 | sch |
|  1  | john |    |    | sch |
|  2  | mary | l1 |    |     |
|  3  | zack | l1 | l2 |     |
|  4  | paul | l1 | l2 | sch |
```

Either l1 or l2 is filled, or both can be filled

Not every 'sch' has a value

What I do is to calculate a daily summary table, but I do it via PHP, I am wondering if it can be done just using SQL. So eg,

```
- Total count (This is just count(name))
- Count(sch)
- If !empty (l1) OR !empty (l2) THEN l + 1
```

So now, based on the above

```
 Total count = 4
 count(sch) = 2
 count(l1 || l2) = 3
```

Can it be done in SQL?

Comment: How about instead of `count( l1 || l2 )` you get the count of l1 AND l2 being null.  Then the count you want is the total count minus count of l1 AND l2 being null.

Comment: Hi HeartfanJohn, Yes that is possible as well. Thanks. But still I am looking to try to do it in an SQL query instead of pulling out the values and counting them in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(name) name_count,
       count(coalesce(nullif(l1,''), nullif(l2,''))) l1_or_l2_count,
       count(sch) sch_count
  from your_table;
```

Comment: HI, I've tried that, all my counts are the same as count(name) which is 4

Comment: Then you must have empty strings instead of null values. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also, side question, is it recommended to have empty strings, or should I mark the field as NULL?

Comment: @user1053408 - It depends on who you talk to. Many in the relational world prefer NULLs, many non-relational developers prefer empty strings. I work in both worlds, and I generally prefer NULLs.

Comment: Another question, what if I have a mixture of empty strings and NULL. Will nullif still work?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say if l1, l2 and sch columns could contain NULL or not.

If these columns can not contain NULL, the mysql query would be like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(sch<>'') AS count_sch,
SUM(l1<>'' OR l2<>'') AS count_l
FROM your_table
```

If these columns can contain NULL, the mysql query would be like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(sch IS NOT NULL) AS count_sch,
SUM(l1 IS NOT NULL OR l2 IS NOT NULL) AS count_l
FROM your_table
```

Comment: I did this SELECT COUNT(sid) AS total, COUNT(sch) AS sch FROM table. What I got is total = 4 and sch = 4

Comment: Could you try the queries in my answer and tell me if it works as you want?

Comment: I replaced "COUNT" with "SUM" for the last 2 result fields (count_sch and count_l), I think it should work better.

Comment: Another question, what if I have a mixture of empty strings and NULL

Comment: Use [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) or `IS NOT NULL` to test fields that can contain NULL, and `=''` or `<>''` to test fields that can contain empty strings (length=0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
select count(*) as count, count(sch) as school,
       sum(case when l1 is not null or l2 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from table
```

Comment: HI, I've tried that, all my counts are the same as count(*) which is 4

Comment: That would suggest that the values are blank rather than NULL.